# How to make rabbitmq management console available for local host (127.0.0.1) and server's external IP address

Tags: rabbitmq

I want my rabbitmq management console configured for both localhost (127.0.0.1) and IP address 10.10.136.19.

I changed the attribute "management.tcp.ip" in rabbitmq.conf, but could not find any of them working. Can some one shed some light here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the management console listens on all addresses, so you should *not* set `management.tcp.ip`.

---

In the future, when asking questions about *any* software, you should always provide this information:

- Software versions.
- Full, unabridged configuration files.
- Logs, or command output. In this case some `curl` commands would have been appropriate.

---

<sub>**NOTE:** Team RabbitMQ monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.</sub>